# How to retrieve request parameter in spring integration http-inbound-gateway by spring el?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el, http-request-parameters

I have a http-inbound-gateway and I want to retrieve a request parameter to fill in the inbound channel as payload.  I find that http-inbound-gateway supports spring expression, so I can use #requestParams to retrieve request parameters. It seems #requestParams is equivalent to request.getParameters('key') which returns a Map but I expect to invoke request.getParameter('key') which returns a String. Currently I have to use new String(#requestParams['key']) to fix this. Is there any better way to do this?

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="/mypath"
    supported-methods="GET" payload-expression="new String(#requestParams['key']?:'')"
    request-channel="inboundChannel" reply-channel="outboundChannel"
    error-channel="errorChannel"
    message-converters="stringHttpMessageConverterUsingUtf8">       
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the source code in org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private Message<?> actualDoHandleRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
//omitted codes
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = this.convertParameterMap(servletRequest.getParameterMap());
        evaluationContext.setVariable("requestParams", requestParams);
//omitted codes    
}
```

so the #requestParameters is a LinkedMultiValueMap object. I can use

```
#requestParams.get('your key')?:''//null safe
```

to get the desired String request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `requestParams` variable is an object of [LinkedMultiValueMap](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html) type. [LinkedMultiValueMap#get](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) method returns List. So your code `#requestParams.get('your key')?:''//null safe` returns list of Strings. It will work fine in most cases, but for example the comparison `(#requestParams.get('your key')?:'').equals('value')` will fail. The full null safe code for getting first string parameter is:

```
(#requestParams.get('your key')?:{''})[0]
```

Note that `LinkedMultiValueMap` is storing multiple values in a `LinkedList`. If you need only one request parameter value you can consider using [LinkedMultiValueMap#toSingleValueMap](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html#toSingleValueMap--) method.